# Javascript not going to the else block

Tags: javascript, css

My if condition works but it does not go to the else block.I do not know if the problem is from using `.css("right")`.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#col1' ).click(function(){
       if($('#col1').css("right")=="10px")
       {
          $('#slider').animate({"left": '-=1280px'});
          $('#slider2').animate({"left": '-=1280px'});
          $('#slider3').animate({"left": '-=1280px'});
          $('#slider4').animate({"left": '-=1280px'});
          $('#slider5').animate({"left": '-=1280px'});
          $('#slider6').animate({"left": '-=1280px'});
          $('#slider7').animate({"left": '-=1280px'});
          $('#slider8').animate({"left": '-=1280px'});
          $('#slider9').animate({"left": '-=1280px'});

       }
       else{
           window.alert(5 + 6);
       }

   });
});
```

Comment: Show us the CSS and HTML

Comment: And perhaps verify there are no errors on the console...

Comment: There are no errors n the CSS or HTML which is why I used the window.alert but still it does not get into that block. The If works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
if( parseInt( $('#col1').css("right") ) === 10 )
```

Comment: It works now, thanks. Why do I have to parse it. Thanks a million.